# OpenGL window manager - multiple process compositing

Tags: opengl, graphics, window-managers, multiprocess, compositing

I'd like to design a simple window manager capable of compositing the outputs from multiple  processes. My first idea was to only use different threads for standalone applications so I use only one context and share it between the applications' and the manager main thread, but on a second thought that doesn't sound like a good idea, since any of the threads crashing will terminate everything.

So I decided it has to actually support dedicated processes for applications but that brings me to the question, which is how exactly do I stitch outputs from different processes together and in a high-performance manner at that. Copying data from GPU to CPU to share in system memory is simply not an option. From the OpenGL parallel FAQ it became clear that using one context from multiple processes is not possibly, unless it is an indirect which results in very low performance.

So, how are existing window managers doing it? Naturally, I do not expect any low level details, just the general concept overview.

Comment: If your platform exposes handles to the surfaces it draws into, you can do this. WDDM (Windows Vista+) offers things called share handles that serve this purpose, but getting access to one for an arbitrary process is not something you're generally able to do as an end-user (the best the public API offers in this sense is a DWM "thumbnail"). It's much easier on other platforms to roll your own compositing window manager though, particularly Linux. *What platform(s) are you interested in?*

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard and portable solution. Window compositors resort to using vendor specific extensions, and often not even directly. For example Wayland relies on EGL for this. This is due to the fact rendering is historically very fragmented, you have software rendering, you have hardware accelerated Direct2D, Direct3D, OpenGL... That is why buffer sharing has to breach gaps between different technologies. I guess being able to share buffers between different processes for OpenGL by standard would be pretty sweet, but there is no indication of this happening anytime soon...

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - I was hoping for something more portable so it can run on top of existing window managers for windows, linux and android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how are existing window managers doing it? Naturally, I do not expect any low level details, just the general concept overview.

In X11 there are the X11 extensions GLX_ARB_texture_from_pixmap and Render which allow move windows off-screen and bind the window's X11 pixmaps as textures in OpenGL. The moniker how this is implemented is called AIGLX (Accelerated Indirect GLX), which despite the name does not depend on an indirect GLX context. Indirect in this case means that everything happens on the display server.

Your compositing window manger will *never* talk to the other processes directly. Instead it just uses the resources and data already present in the X11 server to composit the final result.

This is different from Wayland, where the compositors *do* talk to the other processes directly to exchange framebuffer information. Personally I like the X11 model better, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I've read that X is bloated, over-complicated and on top of that, responsible for rendering the applications rather than the applications being responsible for rendering themselves. This is not ideal, but on the other side it is still more usable than the corresponding M$ windows APIs and more supported than Wayland. I really like Wayland BTW, but at this point it doesn't look like it is too usable, if I understood correctly, it only works with the "open source" drivers whose performance is still severely lacking to that of proprietary driver blobs, which sadly are not in a hurry to support WL

Comment: I'd call X not really bloated. It's just an awful lot to do for the X server. Also X rendering the applications is IMHO a very desireable thing. Because when each application is rendering itself, each application has to deal with all the nasty details that are happily abstracted away in the display server. IMHO Wayland is great as a backend protocol between a display server and the graphics drivers. But IMHO it sucks as a frontend protocol. I've experimented with it (more so in the past weeks, due to my low latency graphics experiments).

Comment: @user3735658: On my desktop, which I just powered off, I got saved a wonderfully illustrative screenshot, why applications should get only abstract access to the display system and not render their stuff themselves: It's a screenshot of a MPD client, written in GTK and in the album list it manages to completely mess up the subpixel antialiasing and font rendering; it looks like it tries to apply some scaling transformations, but somehow those end up transforming the already rendered image and clobber it into the wrong subpixels. When it comes to graphics applications are like little children.